# Release Exam Video Training

Tags: summer-16, release, release-exam

There used to be release exam videos that highlighted the newest features of the release and prepared certified professionals for the release exams.  Are these no longer available?  If not, is Trailhead now the source for that training?

Answer (score 5):

There are videos available at this [link](https://www.salesforce.com/video/release-readiness-summer-2016) covering all the different areas or the more specific ones at [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjJeA2SstEtJ4BvRGPfuBcubf4pISnWA3).

The Trailhead module is additional information and obviously helpful in ensuring the knowledge is picked up.

They don't seem to link them as clearly from the Credential Maintenance areas as they used to.